# Why does bash regex fail for meta characters?

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I am trying to do a bash script to check if input file name is of format name.json.
The regx in bash doesn't work but it works with grep.

file `t1.sh`

```
echo "$1"
regx="^[\w\d-]+[.]json$"
echo $regx
[[ $1 =~ $regx ]] && echo "match" || echo "No Match"
echo $1 | grep -P $regx
test=$(echo $1 | grep -P $regx)
[[ -z $test ]] && echo "Grep No match" || echo "Grep match"
```

Output

```
$ ./t1.sh test-file.json
test-file.json
^[\w\d-]+[.]json$
No Match
test-file.json
Grep match
$ ./t1.sh test-file123.json
test-file123.json
^[\w\d-]+[.]json$
No Match
test-file123.json
Grep match
$ ./t1.sh test-file$.json
test-file$.json
^[\w\d-]+[.]json$
No Match
Grep No match
```

Why is bash not able to process any meta-characters? I thought quoting the regx solved the issue of escape characters.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator, would that help here? I don't see shellcheck output anything about the regex issue.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments hint, there are multiple different incompatible ways that people have chosen to implement regular expressions. The fine bash manual points you to the regex manual in section 3, which points you to the regex manual in section 7. Reading that tells you that `[\w\d-]` will match one of the three characters `w` `d` `-`.

Using `[[:alnum:]-]` in place of `[\w\d-]` will do what you appear to want to do.

Comment: Minor correction: in bash (and anything else that uses POSIX "extended" regex syntax) `[\w\d-]` will also match a backslash character.

Answer (score 0):

As otherwise mentioned, there are different implementations of/extensions to regex in different tools.

If `grep -P` does what you want (FYI the switch you have used enables Perl Compatible Reg Ex features, not usually present in `grep`), then just use that. In your example it would be better implemented as follows:

```
grep -Pq "$regx" <<< "$1" && echo "Grep No match" || echo "Grep match"
```